# Factoring for extremely large numbers that are a power of 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

This is a variation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176607/determine-the-number-of-factors-for-extremely-large-numbers) question. I want to find the number of factors for a given large integer that I already know to be a power of 2.

Given that the number is a power of 2, does that help by eliminating most scenarios e.g.

- factors cannot be odd.
- at least one number of a factor pair has to be a power of 2 itself.

Question:

- What other properties does the power series of 2 have that I can use to find factors more efficiently?
- How can I represent the same in the form of an equation or function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Unique Factorization Theorem? It's a must for anyone interested in factoring integers.

Comment: What do you mean by the "power series of 2"?

Comment: @mike, I take it Raheel just means the series of powers of 2.

Comment: @mike4ty4: Gerry's comment is correct. I meant any number that is a power of 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I am not familiar with that and am looking it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already know the number is a power of 2, then all the factors are also powers of 2. So, if $n=2^k$, then the factors are $1, 2, 2^2, \dots 2^k$, and there are exactly $k+1$ of them.

Comment: I suppose you might not know which power of $2$ your integer is, but it's pretty easy to find out quickly.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial. The prime factors are just 2, repeated. The divisors are $2^m$ for $0 \le m \le \lg(n)$, where $n$ is the power of 2 to be factored. The number of such divisors is then $\lg(n) + 1$. (Here, $\lg$ is the base-2 logarithm.)